# Browser back button loads old page with old javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Page 1 has the flowing code logic when pressing a button

```
If MyDataIsValid() Then
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(me, me.GetType(), "PopUp", "", False)
    Response.Redirect("~/Page2", false)
Else
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(me, me.GetType(), "PopUp", <some js for a popup>, False)
End If
```

If the fist time I press the button and the data is not valid then then popup will show. 
The second time I use valid data and the page redirects to Page2.
If I navigate backwards by pressing the back button on the browser, the popup will show. That's the problem, the popup will falsely tell me my data is not correct.

I know I can make a button on Page2 to redirect me to Page1 but I also want the back button of the browser to work correctly.

When navigating backwards using the browser back button the Load event in Page1 does not run. The page loads the cached page of the first time I press the button.

I tried

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

or the

```
Response.Buffer = true
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
Response.Expires = -1441
```

so the page will no cache but it dos not work. The page does not reload at back button from the browser.

Comment: it doesn't have anything to do with caching, by registering the startup script and performing a postback you're rendering an inline (injected) script into the page.  edit: the back button does pull a cached page, but it isn't an client request and server response scenario.

Comment: you should probably introduce conditional checks into this popup script that suppresses it for this back button scenario.  something like a check to ensure the control view state are the same.  can you provide a sample of `<some js for a popup>` and the form.  Also, please add the appropriate application tag.. I'm getting the impression this is a webform, is that right?

Comment: @Brett Caswell: "the back button does pull a cached page", yes, but it's the page from first time I press the button, not the second time, when the data is valid.

Comment: the distinction here is that you aren't getting a cache as it relates to a request.  the back button is essentially loading a downloaded page from the previous\last response.  A response that has an inline script that executes without condition.

Comment: @BrettCaswell , Correct. Problem is how do I remove the inline script. If I reset the inline script before redirecting it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is your solution: 
Setting your script to Blank/Nothing before you redirect routes to another page.

```
Private Sub WebForm1_PreLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreLoad
    If Session.Item("Script") IsNot Nothing Then
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "PopUp", "<script type='text/javascript'>" & CStr(Session.Item("Script")) & "</script>", False)
    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If MyDataIsValid() Then
        Session.Item("Script") = ""
        Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx")
    Else
        Session.Item("Script") = "alert('Script is running')"
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "PopUp", "<script type='text/javascript'>" & CStr(Session.Item("Script")) & "</script>", False)
    End If
End Sub
```

To avoid cached pages by browser work on it history by Javascript (client side) as follows.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If MyDataIsValid() Then

        Session.Item("Script") = ""
        Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx")

    Else

        Dim sbScript As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        sbScript.AppendLine("( function () {   window.history.pushState(window.history.state, " &
                            " 'Not allowed', " &
                            " 'https://yourdomain.com/page2.aspx'); }()); ")

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me,
                                            Me.GetType(),
                                            "PopUp",
                                            "<script type='text/javascript'>" & sbScript.ToString & "</script>",
                                            False)

    End If

End Sub
```

*However make all control validation by Javascript if it is possible as Client side have more control on Browser than Server side*

Comment: @BrettCaswell, Yes. You was right, the first solution was not the better (it doesn't work properly in all browsers). I've updated the answer with the next solution around the question

Comment: Yep, I think this is a solution.  It's a little different from what I referenced to in comments (uses session state vs control view states), but I think easier to work it (and probably more accurate).

Comment: When the back button from the browser is pressed the page does not realod from server. The method WebForm1_PreInit is not called.

Comment: Use PreLoad event

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj You don't understand, the server is not called. I tried all of then, the PreLoad, Load, PreInit.

Comment: yeah.. I don't know why I fogged over that.. that's right, the solution can't be server-side.. it has to be a check that occurs in the script itself.  as I had mention before.. no request is going to be made to the server when clicking the back button except in the interpetation of the page.  so, you can check against cookies, localstorage as state.. that sort of thing. but you would have to manage it all over the place.. otherwise, you would make this injected script do a call using ajax or something.  use WebMethod on the page perhaps?

Comment: @mvaculisteanu For cached pages I’ve updated the answer. If there is no reason to go back remove/replace the entire history that have your pages in that moment (the only way if the server is not called is working by javascript on document ready before you leave the page in other routes)